# Highcharts label format with tickPositioner in a datetime x Axis

Tags: highcharts

In my chart ,I try to display only 5 ticks in a datetime axis, I use the tickPositioner function and set only 5 ticks ,this work perfect but the data labels loss it's format and show only numbers.

I use the formatter function but i need a grouping labels for the zoom.

Comment: Can you show some representative code or an example image of what is happening vs what you want to happen? What is your code for the formatter function? What does your data look like?

Answer (score 5):

It's little hacky, but you need also calculate information about labels and add them, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/AVhaL/

```
        tickPositioner: function (min, max) {
            var ticks = this.getLinearTickPositions(this.tickInterval, min, max),
                tLen = ticks.length;

            ticks.info = {
                unitName: "week",
                higherRanks: {},
                totalRange: ticks[tLen - 1] - ticks[0]
            };
            return ticks;
        }
```

So according to `totalRange`, you need to pass `unitName` - it's information which format should be taken from [dateTimeLabelFormats](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats).

Answer (score 1):

You only need format label, after put ticks.

```
  Options.xAxis.tickPositioner = function () {
    const ticks = this.series[0].xData;
    let result = [];

    for (let index = 0; index < ticks.length; index++) {
      result.push(ticks[index]);
    }
    return result;
  };
```

and format xAxis

```
labels: {
    format: "{value:%b-%Y}",
    align: "center"
}
```

to tooltips

```
tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: "",
    valuePrefix: "",
    xDateFormat: "%B - %Y",
    valueDecimals: 0
},
```