# Only 3 steps on xAxis with type xAxis in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to get only three steps on the xAxis, one at start, one in the middle and one in the end. I've played around with `xAxis.labels.steps` but I couldn't get an reliable result.

Note the xAxis type is `datetime`.

Comment: in which chart ? jsfiddle please ?

Answer (score 3):

There is at least three ways to achieve that (which are automatically):

1. Use `tickPositioner` (the best IMHO): you have full access to decide where tick should be set (for example: `[min, average, max]`).
2. Use `tickPixelInterval`: useful only when you have fixed width of the chart, and when interval will be multiple of ncie numbers (like 0 - 1 - 2, or 100 - 200 - 300)
3. Use `tickInterval`: useful only when you know range of xAxis, for example 0-10, so you can set `tickInterval: 5`

And jsfFiddle with compare: http://jsfiddle.net/FQ68Y/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the tickPositions option or the tickPositioner function:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner

```
tickPositions: [0, 1, 2]
```

or something like:

```
 tickPositioner: function () {
            var positions = [],
                tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
                increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 2);

            for (; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
                positions.push(tick);
            }
            return positions;
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this dont work with dateTime. It renders the time in ms onto the chart

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers mention there is the `tickPositioner` field. For some reason it dont work out of the box. I had to add an info property to the returning array to get the xAxis to display formatted dates instead of just the milliseconds, as found in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9B6LY/36/).

```
tickPositioner: function (min, max) {
  var ticks = [min, min + (max - min) / 2, max];
  ticks.info = {
    unitName: 'hour',
    higherRanks: {}
  };
  return ticks;
}
```

Comment: Yes, for `dateTime` axis you need to add `.info` object, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454048/highcharts-label-format-with-tickpositioner-in-a-datetime-x-axis/19493187#19493187).

Comment: Could you explain why? It seems strange to have the additional information stored in the array.

Comment: This is logic from Highcharts implemented firstly in Highstock. I guess when they merging Highcharts into Highstock, they decided that solution. In the fact array is an object too in Javascript. For example `array['info']` means the same as `array.info`.