# Highcharts series graph to start and end on tick and end on max

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, series

I want a highcharts graph, to start and end on tick, and have the final x limit equal to the max value.

Even though my configuration has:

```
    max: 11,
    endOnTick: true
```

I found that the actual final value of the graph is 12.
How do I make it to be 11 without having to change endOnTick to false?

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5VVMm/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case you want to start from 0 and and on 11, what should be between? Between 0 and 11 there is no 'nice labels'. If you don't like solution provided by Highcharts, see [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809531/only-3-steps-on-xaxis-with-type-xaxis-in-highcharts/19810102#19810102). I think that first options suits you the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is to use predefined [`tickInterval`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis), following [will do](http://jsfiddle.net/F9vJT/):

```
xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    step: 2,
    max: 11,
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: true,
    tickInterval: 1
}
```

A little bit trickier is `tickPixelInterval` usage, in your case 50 will do.

Things become even more complicated, if your chart is scalable/zoomable. You'll have to write custom event handler to update those properties, to ensure that your `tickInterval` is diveder to your data range (if it's even possible, i.e. data range is integer, not float) to ensure that your last tick equals max axis value.