# Highstock - custom x axis labels or force x axis labels for specific format

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here's a simple highstock chart on JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/range/

You can see that the highstock chart, somehow figured out to display x-axis labels as

```
22nd Nov, 20 Dec, 17 Jan, 14 Feb....
```

How do I force this x-axis labels to display the 1st of each month? So for example, I would like it to display

```
1 Nov, 1 Dec, 1 Jan, 1 Feb...
```

Plus, if my x-axis range was set to the following

```
range: 1 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one month
```

I want to force-change the x-axis labels so that, instead of 1st of each month, I want to display

```
1 Jan, 7 Jan, 14 Jan, 21 Jan, 28 Jan
```

Basically, I'm looking for a way to change the x-axis labels to display the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you need `ordinal` axis by Highstock? If not, then simply disable it and then set `tickInterval`, just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vrzjp468/

```
    xAxis: {
        ordinal: false,
        range: 6 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // six months
        tickInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
    },
```

And of course, when you need different case, like every two weeks, then set `tickInterval: 14 * 24 * 3600 * 1000`.

In case you need to use ordinal axis, then try to use `tickPositioner`.

Comment: Looks like I need to use "tickPositioner", but the example I saw uses highchart. How does tickPositioner work for highstock where the x-axis is in date format? For example, in the following JSFiddle, I explicitly specified two x-axis labels (http://jsfiddle.net/fjtu03qb/2/), but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I guess that [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454048/highcharts-label-format-with-tickpositioner-in-a-datetime-x-axis) should help you ;) Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543896/highcharts-time-based-quarterly-data-xaxis-label-issue).